# Select case convert date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying an SQL statement for a select case. The 'when' has a convert for a date. It is throwing errors. What am I missing?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    'detail', n.UserName, n.StatusCodeDesc,
    CASE 
       WHEN n.enddate IS NULL AND (n.statuscode = 'L' or n.statuscode = 'P')
         THEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY])
       ELSE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n.EndDate, 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY])
    END,
    n.TC_OBT_STAT 
FROM  
    tbl_ActNightlyFeed n 
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_ActExistingFeed g ON n.Empid = g.Empid
```

Comment: Could you let me know what the error is?

Answer (score 4):

The column alias should only appear after the end of the case expression, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  'detail',
  n.UserName,
  n.StatusCodeDesc,
  CASE 
    WHEN n.enddate IS NULL AND (n.statuscode = 'L' OR n.statuscode = 'P')
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101) 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n.EndDate, 101) 
  END AS [MM/DD/YYYY],
  n.TC_OBT_STAT 
FROM tbl_ActNightlyFeed  n 
JOIN Tbl_ActExistingFeed g ON n.Empid = g.Empid
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the `g` table at all.  I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT 'detail', n.UserName, n.StatusCodeDesc,
       (CASE WHEN n.enddate IS NULL AND n.statuscode IN ('L', 'P')
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101)
             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n.EndDate, 101) 
        END) AS [MM/DD/YYYY],
       n.TC_OBT_STAT 
FROM tbl_ActNightlyFeed n 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Tbl_ActExistingFeed g 
              WHERE n.Empid = g.Empid 
             );
```

If the nightly feed table could result in duplicates, you would still need `select distinct`.  I am guessing that table would not have duplicates.